# How to set shortcut to a line of code in Eclipse IDE editor

Tags: eclipse, delphi, ide, editor, shortcut

I'm after a feature in eclipse that allows me to allocate a shortcut to a line (say line number 55) then go somewhere else in the same file and hit the shortcut then IDE shows me the line 55. I have used this feature in Delphi IDE. Using CNTL + number keys[1,2,...,0] a shortcut to line where the curser is will be created. This shortcut only has effect within the editor and each opened file would have its own shortcuts.
Is there such a feature in eclipse? Is there any plugins out there which adds this feature to eclipse?

Regards,

Ali

Comment: To my knowledge there is no similar feature in Eclipse. The closest I've gotten is to assign the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+K in Eclipse to "Add Bookmark", and Ctrl+Q to "Go to Bookmark". It kind of works, but it's more cumbersome than the Delphi way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default there is no shortcut defined for this task.
I use to define my shortcuts in Eclipse in "Windows/Preferences/General/Keys" type bookmark in the filter text and select the commands you want to define the shortcuts.

My current shortcuts are:

1. <kbd>Alt+Shift+B, Alt+Shift+A</kbd>: Add Bookmark;
2. <kbd>Alt+Shift+B, Alt+Shift+V</kbd>: Show View (BookMarks);

But, I agree, still is not fast as the Delphi predefined shortcuts.

**Update 1:**
[This plugin](http://etc.to/eclipse_bookmarks_plugin) (or its sucessor) seems to offer the option. From their site:

> - Add a numbered bookmark at the cursor: Alt>+[digit]. This creates a
>     quick bookmark with the specified number using a "single" keypress.
>     Only one bookmark of the given number can be present in the workspace.
>     Setting the same number bookmark again will clear the earlier
>     instance.
> - Goto a numbered bookmark: Alt+Shift+[digit]. Moves to the bookmark as
>     it was set using Alt+[digit].

**Update 2:**
Tested (Eclipse Indigo) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can add Bookmarks to the code fragments you think are important to you in eclipse.

I referred [this](http://sandarenu.blogspot.com/2008/02/using-bookmarks-in-eclipse.html) link for the same purpose.