# Is there a way to set shortcut to a line of code in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm after a feature in intellij that allows me to allocate a shortcut to a line (say line number 55) then go somewhere else in the same file and hit the shortcut then IDE shows me the line 55. I have used this feature in Delphi IDE. Using CNTL + number keys[1,2,...,0] a shortcut to line where the cursor is will be created. This shortcut only has effect within the editor and each opened file would have its own shortcuts. Is there such a feature in intellij? Is there any plugins out there which adds this feature to intellij?

p.s. I asked this question regarding eclipse a while back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844757/how-to-set-shortcut-to-a-line-of-code-in-eclipse-ide-editor)

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has bookmarks for this kind of functionality. Press `F11` to toggle a bookmark, `Shift + F11` shows available bookmarks.